# How to display statistics of population on a world map from phpMyAdmin?

Tags: javascript, php, angular

I am new to php and javascript, and right now I am trying to display a world map on a website, where the page will display the world map that shows a population on each country from the database in phpMyAdmin.

The example that I want to do is on the given link:
http://popstats.unhcr.org/en/overview#_ga=2.256036427.1301445856.1575086283-1848294458.1575086283

I have googled some examples, but most of them are using Google Map API, which uses the pointer of Google Map.

Comment: I think you have 2 options, 1: you can show map as SVG yourself and put detail like pie or ... with css on each section (all sections separated with SVG, not CSS), a free source is here: https://simplemaps.com/resources/svg-world. 2: another option is a map API like google map API or open street map and Etc. thies API gives you many customizations for style and manages map. in behind this solution (2) api manage maps as SVG on your page. so if you want more detail, tell what is problem with using google API and we can help you more.

Comment: @Neo Anderson, Thank you very much for your suggestions. I maybe won't use Google API as I won't need any longitude and latitude information. As for the first option, may I know if it is possible to use the SVG map, and then use Javascript to highlight some part of the map. When a part of the map, as in a country is highlighted, it will then shows the number of populations?